# Posting to buisness page in instagram

Tags: instagram-api

I looked on the instagram api aand found no mention of postin picture and hashtag to a busness account other than mine 
Can a user post through ios app to a buisness page in instagram?

Comment: by business page you mean the linked Facebook Page ?

Comment: Did you read [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/v2.11) ? Find Business pages: [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page)